# JUnit tester class runs without a main method. How is this done/possible?

Tags: java, junit

Such as here...

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Test;

public class StaticCalculationTest {

   @Test
   public void addSubTest() {
      // assertEquals(String message, long expected, long actual)
      assertEquals("Error in add()!", 3, StaticCalculation.add(1, 2));
      assertEquals("Error in sub()!", 1, StaticCalculation.sub(2, 1));
   }

   @Test
   public void mulDivTest() {
      assertEquals("Error in mul()!", 6, StaticCalculation.mul(2, 3));
      // assertEquals(String message, double expected, double actual, double delta)
      assertEquals("Error in div()!", 0.5, StaticCalculation.div(1, 2), 1e-8);
   }
}
```

Above sample taken from: http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JUnit_Ant.html

Comment: There is a `main()` method, but it is usually hidden in some IDE or other plugin. Like in the link your posted, the class `java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore` has the `main()` method and is used to run the tests.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - That should be an answer, not a comment.  I would like to upvote it please.

Comment: @DavidWallace You made me do work :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No Java application can run without a `main(String[])` method. It is the single entry point. For JUnit tests, this method is usually hidden behind a plugin. For Eclipse, that seems to be `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner`.

In the link you've posted, they propose `java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore` which sets up your `@Test` annotated methods and `Suite`s and runs them. In similar fashion, `Ant` has `JUnitTask` which somewhere (if you go through its source code) creates a runner to run your tests. That seems to be [`JUnitTestRunner`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.apache.ant/com.springsource.org.apache.tool.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit/1.7.1/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/optional/junit/JUnitTestRunner.java), which actually runs in its own JVM thanks to the `Ant` task.